# No suitable driver found for ucanaccess

Tags: java, html, solr, ucanaccess

I've a .mdb access file and I'm indexing the datas to my solr core. I wrote this java class to index them in solr core. When I'm running this java class as java application, it works fine but when I'm running server side it's not working.

```
package org.solr;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.METHOD;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.XMLResponseParser;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.ContentStreamUpdateRequest;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.CoreAdminRequest;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.UpdateRequest;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.CoreAdminResponse;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.UpdateResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.CollectionAdminParams;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.CoreAdminParams.CoreAdminAction;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.ModifiableSolrParams;
import org.apache.solr.common.util.ContentStreamBase.ByteArrayStream;
import org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DateFormatTransformer;
import org.apache.solr.schema.DateValueFieldType;


public class dbJava {


    public void main(String args[]) throws SolrServerException, IOException {
        Statement state;
        Connection connect;
        try {
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\FTK1187\\Desktop/eArchiveMaster.mdb","FTEC198","");
            state = connect.createStatement();  
            ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TableArchive ORDER BY ID" );

            //System.out.println(count);
            String urlString="http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore";
            HttpSolrClient solr=new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
            ((HttpSolrClient) solr).setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
            //SolrInputDocument document=new SolrInputDocument();
            final String contentStream = "extract this text ...";
            final String contentType = "text/csv;charset=UTF-8";
            final ByteArrayStream byteArrayStream = new ByteArrayStream(contentStream.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), null);
            byteArrayStream.setContentType(contentType);
            final ModifiableSolrParams modifiableSolrParams = new ModifiableSolrParams();
            modifiableSolrParams.add(CollectionAdminParams.COLLECTION, "archiveCore");
            ContentStreamUpdateRequest req = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract"); 
            req.addContentStream(byteArrayStream);
            req.setParams(modifiableSolrParams);
            req.setMethod(METHOD.POST);
            solr.deleteByQuery("*");
            solr.commit();
            long startTime=System.nanoTime();
            while(rs.next()){
                req.setParam("literal.id", String.valueOf(rs.getInt("ID")));
                req.setParam("literal.NameAdded", String.valueOf(rs.getString("NameAdded")));
                req.setParam("literal.DateAdded", String.valueOf(rs.getString("DateAdded")));
                req.setParam("literal.NameModified", String.valueOf(rs.getString("NameModified")));
                req.setParam("literal.DateModified", String.valueOf(rs.getString("DateModified")));
                req.setParam("literal.strSO", String.valueOf(rs.getString("strSO")));
                req.setParam("literal.strCust", String.valueOf(rs.getString("strCust")));
                req.setParam("literal.strOperator", String.valueOf(rs.getString("strOperator")));
                req.setParam("literal.PackName", String.valueOf(rs.getString("PackName")));
                req.setParam("literal.DocName", String.valueOf(rs.getString("DocName")));
                req.setParam("literal.DocType", String.valueOf(rs.getString("DocType")));
                req.setParam("literal.extType", String.valueOf(rs.getString("extType")));
                req.setParam("literal.FileName", String.valueOf(rs.getString("FileName")));
                req.setParam("literal.FilePath", String.valueOf(rs.getString("FilePath")));
                req.setParam("literal.NameDeleted", String.valueOf(rs.getString("NameDeleted")));
                req.setParam("literal.DateDeleted", String.valueOf(rs.getString("DateDeleted")));
                req.setParam("literal.intRev", String.valueOf(rs.getString("intRev")));
                solr.request(req);
            }

            long endTime=System.nanoTime();
            long totalTime=endTime-startTime;
            System.out.println("Done...");
            System.out.println(totalTime);
            String urlReload="http://localhost:8983/solr";
            HttpSolrClient solr_reload=new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlReload).build();
            CoreAdminRequest adminRequest=new CoreAdminRequest();
            adminRequest.setAction(CoreAdminAction.RELOAD);
            adminRequest.setCoreName("archiveCore");
            adminRequest.process(solr_reload);
        } 
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I want to run this java class in my.jsp page using jquery. When I'm clicking the update button it gives me this error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\Users\FTK1187\Desktop/eArchiveMaster.mdb
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.solr.dbJava.main(dbJava.java:60)
    at org.apache.jsp.upload_jsp._jspService(upload_jsp.java:124)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is there any mistake or something?? How can I call the java class in my .jsp file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move the Driver in the JRE/lib/ext